# Need free php based ad management system banner rotator etc - which also has client access - any ideas

Tags: php, open-source, banner

I would like to know of a simple banner management system php based - free to use which would have the facility for clients to log in and see their banner statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

openx , 
the site is : http://www.openx.org

is great to manage all banner and its free.

Comment: I have to agree with Haim here. OpenX (previously phpAdsNew, previously phpAds) is a great tool (and it has been for a while now) for ads management.